# How to beta-test CSS effects?

Tags: css, wordpress, date, web

Hi so I like to customize the CSS for example, the posted dates for my portfolio https://dtxscad.wordpress.com/

So how do I do it wihtout affecting the public from the changes that make on the websites?

So one forum said, .date {visibility:hidden;}

Comment: Depending on the quantity of CSS you want to change, you could try things out in the Chrome developer console (or a browser of your choice, but Chrome has the best dev tools in my experience)

Comment: I was told something to do with having a production server when this question was in super-user?

Comment: Either install locally a copy of the site and then make changes there, or fiddle with dev tools and then make changes. I'd have a separate copy myself. I recommend [Vagrant](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV)

Comment: @BigChris: Run a local copy of your website off your production server and, when you're happy with your new style, copy them to your production site. [@BigChris]:http://superuser.com/questions/1149509/how-to-beta-test-css-effects?noredirect=1#comment1652420_1149509

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to test this small CSS-Change, use the class `.logged-in` before your actual selectors. This way, you will only see them, if you are logged in.

In this case you can use

```
.logged-in .date {
    visibility: hidden
}
```

without affecting the public because you will only see your changes while you are logged in.

**BUT**

Generally, it is considered a bad practice to test your code on a production (visible to visitors) environment because there is a possibility that you produce a bug or forget to, for example, use said `.logged-in`-class while doing so and [Murphys Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)

To test changes on your code without affecting your visitors you will need an environment that is seperate from your live website.

**Recommended (but harder) Way**

1. For starters, download and install [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/)
2. download Wordpress and install it by
3. dropping it in MAMPs htdocs-folder
4. visiting http://localhost/
5. Following through the [install wizard](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress)
6. copying the theme you are using into wordpress/wp-content/themes on your local machine

This way, you can test your changes on a local environment without affecting your visitors.

**Edit:**
as @DBS stated, you could also just use the developer tools. In most recent browsers you just have to press F12 to access them.

Further information on how to use the developer tools for [IE/Edge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), [Chrome/Chromium](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) and [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it in your browser's developer tools. By doing this, your changes will be temporary and will go after refreshing webpage

Comment: What if I didn't refresh the page, and so just got left there, would that just be up to the developer to fix that?